# EditText doesn't store first value typed, then stores previous value as new values are added

Tags: java, android, xml

Here are the XML and Java snippets:

```
    <EditText android:id="@+id/paper_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Select Paper"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:onClick="getPaper"/>

    public void getPaper(View view){
    EditText paperText = findViewById(R.id.paper_text);
    paper = paperText.getText().toString();

}
```

So if I press on the hint, the keyboard shows up and I type in a number such as "1". (I only need integer numbers so I thought I'd set the type to "number" or "phone", but the problem occurs with all types.) When I press return to close the keyboard, the number isn't stored in the variable "paper". (I used the debugger to check). However If I open the keyboard again, press backspace and type any number, it then stores the previous instance of the EditText, in this case 1.

To summarize, if I input the following numbers one after the other, this is what is stored:

input: 2, 3, 3, 1, 2

stores: *blank*, 2, 3, 3, 1

Comment: why you are setting click listener to edit text

Comment: **android:onClick="getPaper"** this line is the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `addTextChangedListener` instead of `onClick()`

Try this

```
    EditText paperText = findViewById(R.id.paper_text);
    paperText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String paper = paperText.getText().toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + paper, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

And Remove `android:onClick="getPaper"` from `EditText`

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/paper_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Select Paper"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:inputType="phone"
/>
```

Comment: I'm a beginner so I'm sorry if I don't fully understand your answer. I've copied your java code into onCreate, removed the String declaration from "paper" since it's a global variable that is declared beforehand and removed the toast since the string is then output in a TextView anyway.

However I get a compiletime error stating: Error:(48, 25) error: local variable paperText is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final. I understand that I need to type "final" somewhere but I'm not sure where it should go.

Comment: @MostafaAmr declare **`EditText paperText`** globle outsise on create method

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code snippet that you have provided, it seems like you have set the onclicklistner in edit text. So when you tap on the edittext as on first time it is blank, your first number is blank and then remaining numbers are stored. 
**FYI** 
The method that you mentioned in onclick attribute has View as an input argument parameter, this is the same view on which onclick or onclicklistner is set. In your case it is edittext, so no need to write findViewById() as this will reduce your app performance.

Answer (score 0):

As various other people have pointed out, do not use `android:onClick`. Think about when this event is fired. It only gets fired when your user clicks/taps the EditText (typing on keyboard is NOT a clicking event).

When you subscribe to onClick listener, your **method handler gets called ONLY when you click on it** (in your case closing the keyboard with back button and then tapping the EditText again to start typing).

On the other hand, if you subscribe to `TextChangeListener`, you get callbacks for every time there is a change in text held by the `EditText`.

Hope that makes things easier to understand. Make sure that you always read the method javadocs or at least the Android documentation.

My guess is that you want the user to type, and then press a button to do something with the typed text. So, just add a `Button` in your layout along with `EditText`, and then subscribe to `onClick` of the button to perform your action based on the value of the `EditText`.